С флешки грузится grub вместо ожидаемого ventoy
Уствновил на флешку ventoy и загнал на нее установочный iso-образ с windows 10. Хочу его установить на другой компьютер, на котором нет ни одной рабочей ОС. Но при включении компьютера появляется приглашение в gnu grub. ventoy не открывается. Чего только не пробовал делать. Хотя перед этим на другом компьютере таким образом был успешно установил windows 10. Можно ли это исправить и если да, то как? Буду рад любой вашей помощи.

Я так понял grub на компьютере находится, следовательно выберите при запуске устройство загрузки (обычно через F12)

Без флешки он не грузится, по всей видимости он на флешке. И грузится даже без жесткого диска.

Иногда пишут что это связано с USB больше 137GB и старым BIOS, у Вас не такой случай?

Флешка 32 гига и старый биос.

Скорее всего придется обновлять BIOS, либо если это HP (можно попробовать флешку 8ГБ) более подробно можно почитать тут

У меня тоже также было, причина этого оказалось что на ПК был вирус и он скрыл папки ventoya и ventoy не мог найти свои файлы я просто update сделать флешку и всё заработоло

Попробуй скинуть с установочной папки ventoy данные на сам диск который называется ventoy
